React: Why does this code automatically run onsubmit?
Here's what I'd like to do:
function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission behavior
  console.log('You clicked submit.');
}

function MyForm() {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default MyForm;

But if I change the return line to:
<form onSubmit={console.log('You clicked submit.')}>

The console.log runs automatically even without submit. Why is this? I am trying to understand how react works. I'm guessing that onsubmit automatically execute all the code within {} on render? Then what happens?

onSubmit should be a function that takes an event as the first parameter, as you are passing it an statement React immediately runs the function when it renders. i.e. change your code to onSubmit={() => { console.log('Submit'); }} and it will trigger when you click submit.

I just checked, and this is literally explained in the first page of React's documentation.
If you really want to "understand how react works", you should start there.

@maxpsz where? i'm not finding which doc you're talking about

https://react.dev/learn#responding-to-events. And the tic-tac-toe example (https://react.dev/learn/tutorial-tic-tac-toe) also include some examples mentioning this.

@maxpsz i've read through that doc before and it did not answer my question.
